# Monte Carlo Tree Search for TicTacToe doesn't block opponent's winning moves

Tags: algorithms, games

I've made a program to play TicTacToe against a human using a Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) with UCB1 for node selection. The program will play moves until it wins but it will not make any attempts to block the other player. Is this the nature of the algorithm or have I made a mistake in implementation?

Comment: good job you weren't programming WOPR

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake--most likely not considering "good" moves on the human's part to be bad moves for it.

Why are you using Monte Carlo on Tic-Tac-Toe, though?  There are only 1/3 of a million possibilities and less than 20k possible boards (some of which can never exist.)  Exhaustive search should be possible in human-instant time.